# Python & Pandas: display all rows without omitting

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take a look at the data, but when I do

`pd_data.sort('imdb_rating',ascending=False)`, or

`pd_data.sort('imdb_rating',ascending=False).head(100)`,

the data in the middle would get left out. How can I display a bigger set of data?

Comment: ```pd_data.sort('imdb_rating',ascending=False).to_string()```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set pandas display options.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000
```

Comment: But I don't really want to change the default. I just wan to take a look with more data. Is there something like `.head(100, omit = False)`?

Comment: I don't think so.  You can always just set max_rows back to 60 (default) when you're done.  Also, if you want to see the first 1000, you'll need to set max_rows = 2000

Answer (score 6):

Using Pandas context manager is safe way to go here:

```
with pd.option_context("display.max_rows",100):
    print(pd_data.sort('imdb_rating',ascending=False).head(100))
```

This was added to pandas back in 2013 in this [PR](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5752). There are a few docs on how to use it [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.option_context.html?highlight=option_context#pandas.option_context).